# Show running processes only -- *not* threads

Tags: process, ps, thread

How do I show running processes for every user? Only the processes.
I tried `ps -e` or `ps -A`, but it also shows the [ name ] which are threads.

Answer (score 2):

`ps` does **not** show threads-as-such. The processes with names in `[`square brackets`]` are part of the kernel. You can deduce that they are processes and not threads because the have a PID. `ps` simply reads the process table and displays its contents in a readable form. If you don't want to see those kernel processes you can always filter them out:

```
ps fax | grep -v ' \[[^] ]\+]' | cut -c 1-$COLUMNS
```

or

```
ps -ef | grep -v ' \[[^] ]\+]' | cut -c 1-$COLUMNS
```

Comment: They're kernel threads, actually.

Comment: True, they corespond to kernel threads.